# How do i set different urls in react-admin each servers?

Tags: node.js, react-admin

I developing localhost using react-admin (node.js)

And i have two server - (Develop, Live)

When i publish source codes to dev and live, can i set the different urls each server?

I try get server ip first, and then distribution url set in react-admin config,
but i can not get server ip, because react-admin dataProvider isn't provider getServerIP
function. How do i get server ip in react-admin?

I aleady tried bellow source code in react-admin but it's not working.

```
var ip = require("ip");
var url = ip.address();
console.log(url);

export default url
```

Answer (score 0):

For stuff like that I would use .env files with the dotenv package to read the values. That way on your development machine you have env variables that have the address to your localhost, and env variables with the address of your live server.

Then you just have to have a build process that will look at the correct env file, or use env variables from the server.

Could point you in the direction of some tutorials if you need more help with it.